# When I rebase the last commit of a branch, will this bring also the changes done in the previous commits in this branch?

Tags: git

If I rebase a single commit (I) from my-branch to main branch, will I start seeing in the main branch the changes introduced in D, E, H?

```
A---B---C---F---G (main)                A---B---C---F---G---I (main)
         \                                       \          
          D---E---H---I (my-branch)               D---E---H (my-branch)
```

We are not rebasing D, E, H so we are not bringing the history to the main branch, but each commit is supposed to contain a full snapshot of the files...

Edit:
The rebase is done using
`git rebase --onto G H I`

Comment: Rebase does not move the entire snapshot, it tries to work out the differences between H and I and apply those again on top of G. A merge conflict will occur if this is not possible to do automatically. This should also be easy to test in a mock repository, and I always advocate testing yourself as well, both to get the confidence about whatever I, or someone else, Joe Random on the internet, is saying as well as test cornercases you perhaps didn't mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If you *truly* rebase just `I`, saying `git rebase --onto G H I`, that is the same as cherry picking `I` onto `G`. When you do that, Git asks: what would one have to do to turn `H` into `I`? Whatever that is, do it to `G` (and make a commit expressing the resulting state of the project).

So if `H` introduced a new file, let us say, and `I` did not do anything to that file, then that file would not be introduced by cherry picking `I` onto `G`.

(Also, note that unlike your diagram, rebase / cherry pick does not move any commits. It creates new commits, leaving the old commits in place. After rebasing `I` onto `G` you get a new commit with `G` as its parent; `I` is unchanged and unmoved. You might need to reset the branch back by one commit to get something like your diagram. And even then `I` would remain.)

Answer (score 2):

> each commit is supposed to contain a full snapshot of the files...

Yes, a commit *does* contain a snapshot of the files.

But rebasing (or cherry-picking) commits does not mean "add this commit and make its tree the new tree". What git does is applying **the delta calculated between the commit and its parent** to another base (here, `G`).

As an aside, rebasing `my-branch` on `main` *would* bring copies of `D`, `E` and `H` along with `I`, but you still can cherry-pick (or rebase) `I` on top of `main`

```
git checkout main
git cherry-pick my_branch
```

which will result in

```
A---B---C---F---G---I' (main)
         \
          D---E---H---I (my-branch)
```

where `I'` is a copy of `I` (and potential conflict resolutions)

But the conclusion is **rebasing or cherry-picking one commit does not bring all its ancestry of changes**, it just adds a copy of that commit's changes on the destination.

Comment: You are just repeating the question. The OP already claims to be rebasing one commit only, which _is_ cherry picking.

Comment: I'm not proposing cherry-pick as an alternative solution, I was trying (not a great success, as it seems :-) to explain the *why* about the trees and deltas. Which point should I improve, if I may ask?

Comment: Also, OP's end result schema was flawed so I supposed it was useful to propose the real result a rebase/cherry-pick would produce.

Comment: Good point, I'll mention that in my answer.